# Why is this code printing a random character inbetween the input and output lines?

Tags: c, arrays, printf, character

I'm trying to write a program (in C) where the input is reversed and printed in reverse line by line. For the most part, the code actually does just that. The trouble is that for some (most) of my input, I will get a random character or an extra newline in between my input and my output in the console.

For example, I start the program, type "testing" into the console, and get "gnitseT" back after hitting enter. This has happened successfully and is what I expect. It looks like this:

---

Testing

gnitseT

---

But then when I type "Hello" into the console, it looks like this:

---

Hello

g                (unexpected)

olleH

---

Or if I type "running" into the console, instead of getting an unexpected "g" in between my input and output lines, I get an extra newline.

---

Running

newline here

extra newline here (unexpected)

gninnuR

---

```
#include <stdio.h>




void reverse(int length, char s[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = length; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}


int main(void)
{
    char smain[2000];
    int c;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        smain[i] = c;
        i++;
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            reverse(i, smain);
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The expected behavior is for the program to output into the console the reversed input after the enter key is pressed.

Sometimes, especially at the very beginning of the program, it will work perfectly.

Then, it starts giving me a random character in between my input and output, or it starts giving me an extra newline.

I would like to have it so that it just prints the input in reverse order without any unexpected odd characters showing up in between the input and the output.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why is `c` an `int` instead of a `char`?

Comment: So that it can deal with EOF. I changed it to char and the problem persists.

Comment: I think there's a problem with where your `for` loop starts and end.

Comment: Another nice [`OB1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) example.

Comment: It was indeed an off by one problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is you are reading and attempting to print one character past the end of the characters stored in your array with

```
for (i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%c", s[i]);
}
```

Why? You add `length` characters to `smain` in `main()`. In C, arrays are *zero-based*. The characters in your string are from `0 -> length-1` (the *nul-character* in a *string* is located at `s[length]`, but here you never add a *nul-terminating* character, so the value at that index is simply indeterminate). If the element has not been initialized (which it will not be on your first word or any subsequent word equal to or longer than your longest word entered at that time) *Undefined Behavior* results since you are attempting to read and print an indeterminate value from an uninitialized element in array. How your terminal will output the indeterminate is *undefined* -- and may well result in a `G` being printed.

To correct the problem, loop `for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i++)` or very simply:

```
while (length--)
    printf ("%c", s[length]);

putchar ('\n');     /* don't printf a single-character */
```

(**note:** don't call the variadic `printf` function to output a single-character, that is what `putchar()` is for)

Putting it altogether and fixing your logic so you don't add and print the `'\n'` as part of every word you are reversing, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 2048   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

void reverse(int length, char s[])
{
    while (length--)
        printf ("%c", s[length]);

    putchar ('\n');     /* don't printf a single-character */
}


int main (void) {

    char smain[MAXC];
    int c, i = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            reverse(i, smain);
            i = 0;
        }
        else
            smain[i++] = c;
    }
    if (i)  /* protect against file with no POSIX end-of-file */
        reverse (i, smain);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the `if {...} else {...}` logic to prevent adding the `'\n'`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ printf "Hello\nGoodbye\n" | ./bin/prnrevlines
olleH
eybdooG
```

Which will work just as well without the POSIX eof, e.g.

```
$ printf "Hello\nGoodbye" | ./bin/prnrevlines
olleH
eybdooG
```

Comment: "*reading and attempting to print the nul-character*" which *nul-character*? There is not C-string in the OP's code at all but just a `char`-array. The code in fact might even invoke undefined behaviour by reading and printing the uninitialised `i`th element of `smain` (assuming the 0th element to be the 1st).

Comment: "*`printf ("%c", s[length]);

...    /* don't printf a single-character */`*" well ... ;)

Comment: Ah, right you are. I had string stuck in my mind. So it is just good old *UB* accessing and attempting to print an indetermenate value from an uninitialized element -- Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! This did it. Really appreciate it. The main issue appears to have been with the reverse function's for loop trying to print the extra element in the array (solved by putting (length - 1) instead of length). Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it helps. There is a whole class of errors known as the *"Off by one error"* that is exactly this (though it can appear in thousands of different circumstances). Any time loops and indexing are involved, if something weird is happening, double-check for an *off by one error*.

Comment: This definitely helps. I really have to remember that arrays start at 0 in C.

Answer (score 0):

on line 29

```
++i;
```

this means "i" now have length+1 so, you have been out of the string, you can change the program to :

```
#include <stdio.h>




void reverse(int length, char s[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = length; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}


int main(void)
{
    char smain[2000];
    int c;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        smain[i] = c;
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            reverse(i, smain);
            i = 0;
        }
        else i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This code works too, though it doesn't fix the for loop problem like above by doing (length - 1). Instead, it appears to work by not incrementing i when '\n' is entered, which means that the array length will correspond to the input. For instance, if the user inputs abc and hits enter, i will be incremented to 3. There will be 4 array elements (a, b, c, '\n') that fill out 0-3 in the array. So in the reverse function, counting down from 3 (the value of i without subtracting 1 from length) will not result in the function trying to print an element that doesn't exist. Thanks again!

Comment: And the above is just my understanding. If that's wrong, please let me know.